# AIX list out all account password last update date until today

Tags: passwords, aix

I would like to know how to generate the list of all account's password last update ages on an AIX server.

I am so confused about finding the user account as the server does not have an /etc/shadow file. I tried to use `pwdadm -q user01`, but it output an encoded timestamp and don't know how to decode it.

Expected result:

```
user1 - 60 days
user2 - 30 days
```

Answer (score 0):

the lastupdate attribute is output as the usual "seconds since epoch" format, which in most systems (not all!!!) means, the number is the number of seconds elapsed since Jan, 1st 1970. Some rare systems have different epoch zero times, but usually this works.

to get the current value (being "NOW"), try `date +%s` and to convert the number received from pwdadm to a readable date, use e.g. `date --date='@1242483347'`

To get the age of the current pwd (in seconds), just calc the diff between NOW (see above) and the timestamp shown by pwdadm.

Comment: [AIX's date command](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/aix/7.2?topic=d-date-command) does not support the `--date` option.

Answer (score -1):

Here's how I would approach this:

```bash
#!/bin/ksh93

for user in $(lsuser -R files -a id ALL | awk '{ print $1 }')
do
  lastupdate=$(lsuser -C -a lastupdate "$user" | awk -F: 'NR == 2 { print $2 }')
  if [ -z "$lastupdate" ]
  then
    # no timestamp to process
    continue
  fi
  # pwage=$(perl -MTime::Seconds -e 'my $val = Time::Seconds->new(time() - shift); print $val->pretty;' "$lastupdate")
  pwage=$(perl -MTime::Seconds -e 'my $val = Time::Seconds->new(time() - shift); print int($val->days);' "$lastupdate")
  printf '%s - %s\n' "$user"  "$pwage days"
done
```

This shell script loops through the local users (extracting only their username) and attempts to extract the lastupdate attribute. If that attribute exists, we use a short inline perl script to convert the age (`time()` is the current time, `shift` picks up the lastupdate value) into a number of days with the [`Time::Seconds`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Seconds) package's `days()` method. Alternatively, commented out, you could use the same package's `pretty()` method, which would print the age in an expanded format: `user1 - 168 days, 6 hours, 22 minutes, 24 seconds`; if so, adjust the `printf` that follows to omit the "days" bit.